# Editing Text On Separate View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, transition

I'm new to iOS, and am trying to figure something out that is probably basic. I have two UIViews, with four buttons on each page, and four labels underneath each button. Basically, if I push button 1 on view controller 1, I would like all of the labels on view controller two to simply read "1". Here is an image for a better visual:

[image]

Now, I've connected a Modal transition from button 1 to View Controller 2 in IB, and call this method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"number1"]){
        ViewController2 *controller2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
        controller2.label1.text = @"1";
            NSLog(@"Fired");
            NSLog(@"%@", controller2.label1.text);
    }
}
```

It transitions just fine, but doesn't change the label. The NSLogs show that the method does fire, but the label is null. Does anyone know what I need to change here?

I declared my label in ViewController2 like so:

```
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController {
    UILabel *label1;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;

@end
```

Here is the connections inspector for label1:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an entirely new instance of your view controller. The storyboard creates the view controller for you, and passes it to you for configuration in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method. You can access it like so:

```
ViewController2 *controller2 = (ViewController2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
// configure controller2 here
```

Also, outlets on a view controller aren't set when `prepareForSegue:` is called. You need to have an `NSString` as a property on the second view controller. Later, you can use `viewDidLoad` to set the label's text to the value held by the `NSString` property you earlier defined.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the line to the one you posted, however it's still not changing the label. I'm not sure why, it's confusing.

Comment: Do you have the label properly connected to the `ViewController2` in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes I do. Also, I edited my OP to show how I declared it, that may be the issue.

Comment: Is the label still null?

Comment: Yes it is, it still has the standard placeholder text as well.

Comment: I'm not sure you have the label properly connected. Post screenshots of the connections inspector for the label.

Comment: Sure thing, I just posted it

Comment: Post a screenshot of the *connections inspector*, while you have the label selected in storyboard.

Comment: Definitely, it is the last picture in the OP. Unless I did that incorrectly?

Comment: Interesting. Are you doing anything to the label in `ViewController2.m`?

Comment: Nothing at all, just declared and synthesized it.

Comment: Upload your project and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: You're the man, thank you! I just put it on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6jfbazjsiwxmxr/x2project2.zip